# print sum of duplicate numbers and product of non duplicate numbers from the list

Tags: list, python-2.7

I am new to python. I am trying to print sum of all duplicates nos and products of non-duplicates nos from the python list. for examples 
list = [2,2,4,4,5,7,8,9,9]. what i want is sum= 2+2+4+4+9+9 and product=5*7*8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pythonic one liners that can do this but here is an explicit way you might find easier to understand.

```
num_list = [2,2,4,4,5,7,8,9,9]
sum_dup = 0
product = 1
for n in num_list:
    if num_list.count(n) == 1:
        product *= n
    else:
        sum_dup += n
```

Also side note, don't call your list the name "list", it interferes with the builtin name of the list type.

Answer (score 0):

`count` is useful for this. Sum is built in, but there is no built in "product", so using reduce is the easiest way to do this.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

the_sum = sum([x for x in list if list.count(x)>1])
the_product = reduce(operator.mul, [x for x in lst if lst.count(x)==1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop  to read a number from the list. create a variable and assign the number to it, read another number and compare them using an if statement. If they are the same sum them like sameNumSum+=sameNumSum else multiply them. Before for loop create these two variables and initialize them. I just gave you the algorithm to it, you can change it into your code. Hope that help though.